# regex: match string where n number of alphabets mandatory and optional numerics and underscore

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate a username field like this:

1. 6 alphabets mandatory
2. Might contain any number of numericals
3. Might contain any number of underscores

For example: **abcdef**, **abc9def**, **_testaa**, **__test_aa_**, **hello_h_9**, **_9helloa**, **9a8v6f_aaa**
All these should match, that is, the number of alphabets should be more than n numbers (here 6) in the whole string, and _ and numerics can be present anywhere.

I have this regex: `[\d\_]*[a-zA-Z]{6,}[\d\_]*`
It matches strings like: _965hellof
But doesn't match strings like: ede_96hek

I also have tried this regex: `^(?:_?)(?:[a-z0-9]?)[a-z]{6,}(?:_?)(?:[a-z0-9])*$`
Even this fails to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a lookahead like this:

```
/^(?=[^A-Za-z]*([A-Za-z][^A-Za-z]*){6}$)\w+$/
```

This is in two parts, the long part verifies there are exactly 6 alphabetic characters present without moving the scanners cursor position.  Then the \w+ says **all** the characters must be alphanumeric or underscore.  The ^ & $ ensure the entire string conforms.

Comment: thanks. what does the ?= do? Can you please explain the whole expression?

Comment: (?= kicks off a lookahead.  Lookaheads scan forward for the pattern but they don't move the regex cursor, so after that paren is closed, it starts scanning again from where it started.

Comment: Also it works, but doesnt work for cases like `_testaa` or `123testaa`

Comment: Fixed case when it does not start with alpha.  Try it again

Comment: The OP says "the number of alphabets should be more than n numbers (here 6)", and this fails when there are more than 6 alphabets.

Comment: Actually, OP says 6 mandatory and then gives all examples with EXACTLY 6 alphas.  Sounded like 6 and only 6 to me.  If you want to change it to minimum 6, then put a comma after the 6.

Comment: Which part of the wording in "the number of alphabets should be *more than* n numbers (here 6)" is unclear to you? The OP has also posted two of his own attempts, both with the quantifier `{6,}`. The intended behavior is more than clear to me. The word "mandatory" on the other hand has double meanings. It can mean "exactly", yes, but can also mean "at least".

Answer (score 2):

One solution is splitting the `str` and on each character checking if it's an alphabet with `.filter(v => isNaN(v) && v !== '_')` and then get the `length` to check if it's more than 6 alphabets.

```js
const checkValidation = (str) => {
  return /[\d\_a-z]/gi.test(str) && str.split('').filter(v => isNaN(v) && v !== '_').length >= 6
}

console.log(checkValidation('something_123'))
console.log(checkValidation('12somtg1'))
console.log(checkValidation('123some12tg'))
console.log(checkValidation('123some12_'))
console.log(checkValidation('_965hellof'))
console.log(checkValidation('ede_96hek'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
^\w*(?:[A-Za-z]\w*){6,}$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/yoGr82/1